# How to differentiate between cellular operators in an Android application?

Tags: android, c, mobile, at-command, cellular-network

I have an Android application which uses an `.so` file, The `.so` changes his behavior according the network the phone connected to, i.e. if you are connected to `AT&T` you need to do `XYZ`. if you work on `Verizon` you do `ABC` otherwise you do `XY`.

1. Is there any good way to differentiate between mobile networks?
2. I thought to use [PLMN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_land_mobile_network) somehow, Is there any robust way of doing
   that? (I want it to work while roaming too etc.).

I had seen [this](http://android.riteshsahu.com/tips/programmatically-get-the-current-network-operator-name), but I need to do it only in the C code with no wrappers or Java engagement, meaning the following can't be used:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =((TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String operatorName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

Comment: When you say you want it to work while roaming, do you mean that while roaming, you want the behaviour of the home Network, or you want the behaviour of the current Network?

Comment: @SList, I Want to the behavior of the current network, otherwise I would differentiate by the SIM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the currently used PLMN with the `AT+COPS?` command. From [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm):

```
+COPS?                               +COPS: <mode>[,<format>,<oper>[,<AcT>]]
```

...

```
Read command returns the current mode, the currently selected operator and the
current Access Technology. If no operator is selected, <format>, <oper> and <AcT>
are omitted.
```

....

```
<oper>: string type; <format> indicates if the format is alphanumeric or numeric;
long alphanumeric format can be upto 16 characters long and short format up to 8
characters (refer GSM MoU SE.13 [9]); numeric format is the GSM Location Area
Identification number (refer 3GPP TS 24.008 [8] subclause 10.5.1.3) which
consists of a three BCD digit country code coded as in ITU-T E.212 Annex A
[10], plus a two BCD digit network code, which is administration specific;
returned <oper> shall not be in BCD format, but in IRA characters converted from
BCD; hence the number has structure: (country code digit 3)(country code digit 2)
(country code digit 1) (network code digit 3)(network code digit 2)(network code
digit 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, BTW, Is there any way to run at commands on Java on unrooted Android phone ?

Comment: I have not tested myself, but as far as I know the modem device files should be accessible (through adb) without rooting the phone. When interacting with a modem from the command line I recommend my program [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Using the following two `at` commands ([see also](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/help/how-to-talk-to-modem-commands-t1471241))

```
AT+COPN         7.21            -  Read operator names 
AT+COPS         7.3             -  PLMN selection
```